Grafana db query error / SQL Server : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'
SELECT 
    DK_KOD, $__time(DATEADD(HOUR, -3, MQ_TAR_ZMN)), 
    SUM(ADET) AS toplam
FROM 
    [MYDB].[dbo].[Sayi] 
WHERE
    DK_KOD = 'XYZ' 
    AND (TXN_KOD = 'A' OR TXN_KOD = 'B' OR TXN_KOD = 'C' 
         OR TXN_KOD = 'D' OR TXN_KOD = 'E' 
         OR TXN_KOD = 'F' OR TXN_KOD = 'G')
GROUP BY
    DK_KOD, DATEADD(HOUR, -3, MQ_TAR_ZMN) 
ORDER BY
    DATEADD(HOUR, -3, MQ_TAR_ZMN)

As a result of this query I sent to SQL Server data source in Grafana, I got an error

db query error: mssql: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

I removed the AS keywords and it didn't help, I tried whatever chat gpt suggested and it didn't work.
Can you help me with this? I want to plot the data result as a time series in Grafana version: 9.3.6.
Thank you in advance

I am curious, what $__time  means

$__time() is the code that converts the selected time to datetime format in Grafana. SSMS also works as you mentioned. I want to get data from Grafana interface.

Remove the ORDER BY.   It can’t appear in a subquery.

I have the same doubt as @Sergey about $__time because you are using the DATEADD inside the $__time Grafana since it expects a datetime column, and the DATEADD function modifies it before passing it to the macro. So try to handle the DATEADD separately.
SELECT 
  DK_KOD, 
  DATEADD(HOUR, -3, MQ_TAR_ZMN) AS time_column,
  SUM(ADET) AS toplam
FROM 
  [MYDB].[dbo].[Sayi] 
WHERE 
  DK_KOD = 'XYZ' 
  AND TXN_KOD IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G')
GROUP BY 
  DK_KOD, 
  DATEADD(HOUR, -3, MQ_TAR_ZMN)
ORDER BY 
  time_column

